# Trackball mouse speed setting resetting every time computer is restarted

Tags: windows-7, mouse

I have a Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit laptop and I use a Logitech Trackman T-BB18. The mouse settings in the control panel keep resetting to the middle point (regarding to mouse pointer speed) whenever I reboot my computer.  In addition the logitech mouse and keyboard settings also resets itself to a previous setting (not necessarily the middle setting).  This causes the mouse to move across the screen much more slowly and has to be reset every time the computer is turned on again.

Comment: Is the driver for the mouse updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that in the mouse settings page, needed to uncheck a box that said retain OS settings. Issue is now resolved.